# Dynamic language change refreshes whole UI but MenuBar

Tags: qt, qml

I have a small issue while dynamically changing the language of my application on the fly.

The language can be selected from a `Menu` in a `MenuBar`, whenever I switch to another language the changes are immediately visible in the UI, except on the `MenuBar`. If I do hover the `MenuBar` or resize the window a bit the `MenuBar` gets updated.

Here's the problem in action:

[image]

I've been trying to find a *refresh* function on QML types but couldn't find any.

**Question**

How to ensure a `MenuBar` gets refreshed after changing language?

**Edit**

Here's the full source of my application:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QQmlContext>
#include "Translator.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
                         if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                             QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
                     }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    Translator translator(engine);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("translator", &translator);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Translator.h

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H
#define TRANSLATOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class Translator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Translator(QQmlEngine &engine, QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void languageChanged();

public slots:
    void setLanguage(const QString &language);

private:
    QQmlEngine &m_engine;
    QTranslator m_trans_fr;
};

#endif // TRANSLATOR_H
```

Translator.cpp

```
#include "Translator.h"


Translator::Translator(QQmlEngine &engine, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),
    m_engine(engine)
{
}

void Translator::setLanguage(const QString &language)
{
    if (language == QString("fr"))
    {
        m_trans_fr.load("WipeoutViewer_fr.qm");
        qApp->installTranslator(&m_trans_fr);
    }
    else if (language == QString("en"))
    {
        qApp->removeTranslator(&m_trans_fr);
    }

    m_engine.retranslate();

    emit languageChanged();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.6

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Wipeout viewer")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Quit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Language")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&English")
                onTriggered: translator.setLanguage("en")
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&French")
                onTriggered: translator.setLanguage("fr")
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Help")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&About")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I've updated my question.

Comment: based on the code you have provided I have created the following project https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/56103353/56103353-2 And it works for me correctly, try to test my code and if it does not work then it is probably a bug, what is your OS and what version of Qt do you use?  I have run it on Linux with Qt 5.12.3

Comment: I use Win10 and Qt 5.12.2, tried in 5.12.3 and it's the same. I have tried your project but it doesn't build, that `copy_cmd` is confusing XCOPY with `Does WipeoutViewer_fr.qm specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?`

Comment: remove the copy_cmd command from the .pro and manually copy the .qm to the side of the executable

Comment: Got your project working now but unfortunately it's the same exact result :(

Comment: Then it's a bug, report it

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22435

Comment: The bug is not QtCreator but Qt, you must report it in https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTBUG/

Comment: right :) ... fixed! https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75778  thanks for your help!